# Loading a class method when Apache Axis 2 starts up

Tags: java, apache-axis

I need to execute a static method in a Java class when the Apache Axis 2 starts, or something which could be done in an application scope.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and add it to your deployment descriptor (`web.xml`):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.pack.age.path.YourServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The [`contextInitialized`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method will be called immediately after your servlet context is loaded so you can place your static method call inside.

One other way you could do it is to extend Axis2’s Servlet and do your initialization there.

In `web.xml` you replace the Axis2 Servlet with your own:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Axis2Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>your.pack.age.path.YourAxis2Servlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Your Servlet:

```
package your.pack.age.path;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet;

public class YourAxis2Servlet extends AxisServlet {

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    // your initialization code here
    //...
  }  
  //...
}
```